# Using TestHiveContext/HiveContext in unit tests

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I'm trying to do this in unit tests:

```
val sConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("RandomAppName")
  .setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sConf)
val sqlContext = new TestHiveContext(sc)  // tried new HiveContext(sc) as well
```

But I get this:

```
[scalatest] Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient *** ABORTED ***
[scalatest]   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
[scalatest]   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:120)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:163)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:161)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:168)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.test.TestHiveContext.<init>(TestHive.scala:72)
[scalatest]   at mypackage.NewHiveTest.beforeAll(NewHiveTest.scala:48)
[scalatest]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.beforeAll(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:187)
[scalatest]   at mypackage.NewHiveTest.beforeAll(NewHiveTest.scala:35)
[scalatest]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:253)
[scalatest]   at mypackage.NewHiveTest.run(NewHiveTest.scala:35)
[scalatest]   at org.scalatest.Suite$class.callExecuteOnSuite$1(Suite.scala:1491)
```

The code works perfectly when I run using spark-submit, but not in unit tests. 
How do I fix this for unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but I ran into similar issues, I ended up using [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base):

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.SharedSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.test.TestHiveContext
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class RowToProtoMapper$Test extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {

    test("route mapping") {
        val hc = new TestHiveContext(sc)
        /* Some test */
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I get null pointer Exception at the row where I have `val hc = new TestHiveContext(sc)`